# Ember redirect and display template correctly

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, handlebars.js, ember-router

So I decided to give Grunt a try to precompile my templates for me. I am having trouble setting everything up. Here is what I have inside my Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ember-templates');

  emberTemplates: {
  compile: {
      options: {
        templateBasePath: "templates/",
        templateName: function(name) {
          return name.replace('_','/');
        }
      },
      files: {
        "templates/templates.js": ["templates/*.hbs"]
      }
    }
  }

  watch: {
    emberTemplates: {
      files: 'templates/*.hbs',
      tasks: ['emberTemplates', 'livereload']
    },
  }
```

I believe this is fine since I referenced the document. My package.json has the dev-dependencies. However when I try do grunt --help, no available tasks show up.

Comment: I was able to just append the response html to the body. I was hoping that ember naming conventions would be able to look up the right template for me. Is there a standardized way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points to be noted:

- Templates are required to be loaded to Ember.TEMPLATES not Handlebars.Templates.
- You should use Ember.Handlebars.compile rather Handlebars.compile. You think its just a wrapper but it may be doing more with extra ember helpers and all.

Also I answered how can we go with template compiling with multiple files. Following link may be useful
[ember hbs templates as separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566795/ember-hbs-templates-as-separate-files/18567174#18567174)

Comment: Cool. Actually I am trying another alternative to this, I am trying to user a grunt plugin called grunt-ember-templates to precompile my ember templates for me. I am new to grunt also. I was wondering how to execute the grunt commands.

Comment: Right now this is in my gruntFile.js:
`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ember-templates');

  emberTemplates: {
  compile: {
      options: {
        templateBasePath: "templates/",
        templateName: function(name) {
          return name.replace('_','/');
        }
      },
      files: {
        "templates/templates.js": ["templates/*.hbs"]
      }
    }
  }

  watch: {
    emberTemplates: {
      files: 'templates/*.hbs',
      tasks: ['emberTemplates', 'livereload']
    },
  }` Is this the correct way of setting it up?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that I was not aware of the order for putting code inside the Gruntfile.js. I was supposed to

1. put the emberTemplates inside the grunt.initConfig()
2. load the NPMtask then
3. register the task