# Version compatible issue with ember-precompile, ember.js and handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I cannot read the precompiled templates in my html. It is due to the version compatible issue of ember-precompile with ember.js and handlebars.js.

My code goes like this:

Included the below files.

```
<script src="../js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="../js/libs/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="../js/libs/ember-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/precompile.js"></script>
<script src="js/precompile.app.js"></script>
```

Reading my compiled template inside body tag.

```
<div id="tempdiv">haii</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var compiledTemplate = Em.TEMPLATES["precompile"];
    var temp_html = compiledTemplate({ name: 'World' });
    console.log(temp_html);  //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined 
    $("#tempdiv").html(temp_html);
</script>
```

I have already downloaded npm handlebars compiler version in command prompt as:

```
npm install handlebars@1.3.0 -g
```

In console the handlebars COMPILER_REVISION is coming as 4

```
Handlebars.COMPILER_REVISION  -- 4
```

With the above versions i can read the templates using Handlebars as

```
Handlebars.templates['test_temp'];
```

Then i installed ember-precompile from the below package -

> https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-precompile

Installed in command prompt as:

```
npm install ember-precompile
```

Now I am not able to read the compiled templates using Em.TEMPLATE["template_name"].

There is compatible issue with the versions of ember, handlebars and ember-precompile I have included and installed.

What version of each one matches and can read the compiled templates.

Comment: provided answer by GJK is correct....add the stacktrace of the error you are getting for push...i am not sure if it is from templates..You can check if you are using correct version here https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates#release-history

Answer (score 0):

I always had problems with `ember-precompile` not being updated. Fortunately, you can update the libraries yourself. Just go to the folder where `ember-precompile` is installed (for me, it's globally at `/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/ember-precompile`), and replace the libraries in the `vendor` folder. The latest version uses Ember 1.2.0 and Handlebars 1.1.2. Just replace those with the versions you need. (You might need to keep the same names, but I can't really remember.)

Also, why are you including the precompile Javascript files in your page? That defeats the whole purpose of precompiling.

Comment: thanks for your response. I replaced the ember and handlebars version what I am using in the vendor folder. Recompiled and tested but I am getting the error --> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: I'm getting the same error; did you solve this? Admittedly I'm getting in this in situations where I'm NOT explicitly precompiling (aka, basic "it renders" unit tests)