# Live Handlebars / HTMLBars templates

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I'm looking for an easy, reliable way to lazy load templates in Ember 1.10 but can't find much. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566795/ember-hbs-templates-as-separate-files) and [this discuss.emberjs](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/lazy-loading-ember-controllers-view-and-templates/3607) both ask something similar to what I need for this application.

I've set up Grunt with [`grunt-ember-templates`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ember-templates) to pre-compile the templates. But, by the end of this development, the minified JS file will be in the 3-4 megabyte range, which is not an option.

The questions mentioned above were asked over a year ago. Has anything changed that Handlebars, or better yet HTMLBars templates can be loaded as they're needed? I feel like I'm missing something entirely! Ember was built exactly for the purpose of creating robust applications.

-

**Edit:** The lack of suggestions on a better way to manage template files is worrying. I'm not sure how this wasn't considered a problem right from the start of ember development? There is [the strategy of using a `beforeModel` hook](http://madhatted.com/2013/6/29/lazy-loading-with-ember)  but shouldn't adding templates on-the-fly be implemented already?

Simply put, if I want to display a `.hbs` template inside an HTML file without pre-compiling, what is the easiest and fastest way?

Comment: to be sure, are you using the `minify` flag when pre-compiling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile template client side in ember using HTMLbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316803/compile-template-client-side-in-ember-using-htmlbars)