# Compile template client side in ember using HTMLbars

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

I have created a CMS where it is be possible to use HTMLbars to create templates. The templates should be compiled client side and there is component that should display the template. I'm setting the template property of the component to a function that returns the compiled template using HTMLBars.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  content: null,
  template: function () {
    return Ember.HTMLBars.compile(this.get('content.template'));
  }
}
```

I've included the ember-template-compiler in my Brocfile.

```
app.import('bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
```

also tested

```
app.import('bower_components/ember-template-compiler/index.js');
```

But the template is never rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be a property, and on a component it should be `layout`, but it will only be evaluated once, so updating the content won't rebuild the template.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vayereqapo/1/edit?html,js,output

```
Ember.Component.extend({
  content: {template: 'Hello'},
  layout: function () {
    return Ember.HTMLBars.compile(this.get('content.template'));
  }.property()
});
```

Rerender when template content changes:

```
App.FooBarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  content: {template: 'Hello'},
  foo: function(){
    var self = this;
    Em.run.later(function(){
      self.set('content.template', 'Bye');
      self.rerender();
    }, 3000);
  }.on('init'),
  layout: function () {
    return Ember.HTMLBars.compile(this.get('content.template'));
  }.property('content.template')
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qebuxuxasu/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Will rerender trigger the layout to be compiled again?

Comment: Apparently it will, learn something new every day :)  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qebuxuxasu/1/edit

Comment: I tested it and the property was already there it was just missing here in my example. But I had an old template hbs file connected to the component that had precedence.
After I removed the file it worked fine with template as well.

Comment: Is there any way of validating the compiled template? Now whenever the template is faulty it breaks. I would like to validate it before I insert it in the dom.

Comment: `ember-template-compiler.js` is in JSBin, but it's worth pointing out that you have to load it, in addition to Ember itself.

Comment: this is how you can import `ember-template-compiler` w ember +2.11 https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6712