# Ember - Dynamically create a component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on a module which needs to register components with Ember, Angular, React etc. depending on what is loaded into the page.

With React I can just do

```
if (window.React) {
  React.createClass(...
```

But how can I do the same with Ember? I'm looking for something like:

```
if (window.Ember) {
  Ember.registerComponent('my-component-name', Ember.Component.extend({
    ...
  }));
}
```

Is this possible? Bearing in mind **I don't have access to the Ember App on the page**.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. To break it down a bit, we want to dynamically:

1. Create a subclass of `Ember.Component`.
2. Compile that Component's template.
3. Register that Component in the app's global namespace.

The answer to 1. is already in your question (`Ember.Component.extend`).
2. has been answered elsewhere: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30317961/1067145) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345099/1067145), for instance.

Off the top of my head, I'm not sure of an airtight answer for 3-- I'd recommend looking at using [register](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_register) on Ember's Dependency Injection container, or searching SO specifically for that goal.

---

Be forewarned that this isn't really on the Ember "happy path"-- for performance reasons, Ember (and Glimmer) are mostly focused on precompiled templates.