# Dynamically compile a HTMLBars template at runtime in Ember

Tags: templates, ember.js, compilation, htmlbars

I want to dynamically compile (and then render) a HTMLBars template at runtime, on the client in Ember. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Ember 2.10 is now using Glimmer, things might be a bit tricky here. In order to compile a template, you need to include `ember-template-compiler.js` to your application. I'd recommend using `ember-browserify` and `ember-source`.

In your controller, import the compiler as the following.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Compiler from 'npm:ember-source/dist/ember-template-compiler';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  compileContent() {
    const template = Compiler.compile(this.get('dynamicContent'));
    Ember.TEMPLATES[`YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME`] = template;
  },
  // we observe content changes here
  contentDidUpdate: Ember.observer('dynamicContent', function() {
    this.compileContent();
  }),
});
```

As tested, your content can contain anything from Ember helpers to your custom components, even your action bindings.

e.g.

```
<ul>
  <li>{{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}</li>
</ul>
<div {{action 'yourCustomAction'}}>
  {{your-custom-component params=yourCustomParams model=model flag=true}}
</div>
```

Now, let's do the magic in your template by using `{{partial}}` helper.

```
...

{{partial 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME'}}

...
```

This method works in Ember 2.13 without deprecation warnings, it should work in future updates. Please note that `Ember.TEMPLATES` is global variable and the engine seems to cache it somehow, so do not reassign new values to the existing one.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is now out of date. Please see @poohoka's answer which I've accepted above.

---

Building off of Kingpin2K's answer to [Compile template client side in ember using HTMLbars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30317961/1067145):

For some background, it might be useful to refer back to [Compiling Templates with Ember 1.10](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/compiling-templates-in-1-10-0.html). We'll still need to load `ember-template-compiler.js`. Add

```
  app.import('bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
```

to your `ember-cli-build.js`.

Then you can write a Component like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  layout: Ember.computed(function() {
    return Ember.HTMLBars.compile(
      '{{foo-bar}} <span>' + 'hello' + '</span>'
    );
  }),

});
```

This solution will likely break in future relases of Ember, depending on how the Ember Template compilation process changes with the advent of [Glimmer 2](https://youtu.be/OInJBwS8VDQ?t=45m12s).

Answer (score 3):

Since Ember 2.13+ (without bower by default) you need to add in your ember-cli-build.js:

```
app.import('vendor/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
```

For Ember version prior to 2.10 you need to include it via `bower` (also on ember-cli-build.js)

```
app.import('bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
```

And on the code you need to:

```
Ember.TEMPLATES['mycompiledcode'] = Ember.HTMLBars.compile('{{foo-bar}} <span>' + 'hello' + '</span>');
```

In the hbs file call:

```
{{partial 'mycompiledcode'}}
```

Or you can make a component like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  layout: Ember.computed(function() {
    return Ember.HTMLBars.compile(
      '{{foo-bar}} <span>' + 'hello' + '</span>'
    );
  }),

});
```

Based on solution of another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345099/6505594

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently on Ember-2.9.x and I brought in the latest handlebars with my `bower.json`:

```
"handlebars": "^4.0.0"
```

And then added it via my `ember-cli-build.js` file:

```
app.import('bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js');
```

This has worked for my `typeahead` component and I don't see any reason why this won't work when upgrading to Ember-2.10 with Glimmer2.