# Compiling Ember handle bars template on the fly?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there a way to compile a handlebars template on the fly and insert it into the DOM?

Like say,

```
<a {{action 'callAction' items}}>Some text</a>
```

for now, if this is done using a {{{ }}} this renders as

```
<a {{action 'callAction' [object Object]>Some text</a>
```

and the action will obviously not be fired. Any way to achieve what Ember does while precompile?

EDIT:

I have tried

```
Ember.HTMLBars.compile(<code>)
```

but it returns an object, but not sure how to determine the template out from it.

Comment: Where does `items` come from? What does it contains?

Comment: Items is a property passed from a helper. The helper takes these properties and creates the DOM with actions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically compile a HTMLBars template at runtime in Ember 2.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345098/dynamically-compile-a-htmlbars-template-at-runtime-in-ember-2-5)