# How to add a helper function in a dynamic template for one of the elements in a component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, helper

I'm trying to dynamically create my template as below:

```
template: '<div> <input type="checkbox"  {{report-checkedvalue}} value="#:' + filterField + '#"/>#:' + filterField + '#</div>'
```

report-checkedvalue is my helper which returns checked or unchecked value for my checkbox input. But i can get it to work.I appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you should check out the input helper: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_checkboxes

Comment: You would need to compile the template and then inject it with the view layer. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how things works in angularjs

But here is litle help i can

use conditional string for your template like

```
var isChecked = {{report-checkedvalue}} // true or false
var template = '';
if(isChecked){
    template = '<div> <input type="checkbox"  checked value="#:' + filterField + '#"/>#:' + filterField + '#</div>'
}
else {
    template = '<div> <input type="checkbox" value="#:' + filterField + '#"/>#:' + filterField + '#</div>'
}
```

That will generate checked and non-checked checkbox in your html.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically compile your template on client side, I suggest you to read this answer: [Dynamically compile a HTMLBars template at runtime in Ember 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345098/dynamically-compile-a-htmlbars-template-at-runtime-in-ember-2-5) based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316803/compile-template-client-side-in-ember-using-htmlbars/30317961#30317961).

But this is far from an Ember convention and you probably should avoid if it is not absolutely necessary.